# How to make cancellable timeout callback?

Tags: scala, scala-cats, cats-effect, fs2

I want that user can run a timer with callback and able to cancel it. Something like this:

```scala
def main: F[Unit] =
  for
    cancel       <- runTimer(callback, 5.seconds)
    shouldCancel <- askUser
    _            <- cancel.whenA(shouldCancel)
  yield ()
```

How can I do it in terms of Cats of FS2?

Comment: How exactly it should work? Shout it call a callback after 5 seconds, if user won't cancel it before that, or should it run something and after 5 seconds ask user if they want to cancel it? Either way it sound like: a mix of starting a fiber `GenSpawn[F, E].start(fa)` , running `GenTemporal[F, E].sleep(5.secons)`, some maps and `flatMap`s, or just using `racePair` with `sleep`.

Comment: What is a _"timer with a callback"_? - Something that executes the given _"callback"_ after the specified time?

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok it should start a background process, return `cancel` handler so that user can cancel the process, and executes a callback after supplied duration if the user didn't call `cancel` on the time. If the user did call `cancel` before the timeout, the process do nothing with a callback

Comment: @MaxSmirnov what should happen if the user cancel during the execution of the callback?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez when delay is elapsed and callback started evaluating, user has no way to cancel it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code that you need is actually pretty simple thanks to **cats-effect** being very powerful at solving concurrency problems:

```scala
def runTimer(
  callback: IO[Unit],
  delay: Duration,
  cancel: IO[Unit]
): IO[Unit] =
  IO.race(
    IO.sleep(delay) >> callback.uncancelable,
    cancel
  ).void
```

The key aspects are as follows:

- Using `IO.sleep` to delay the execution of the callback.
- Using `uncancelable` to make the callback uncancelable.
- Using `IO.race` to run both the delayed callback and the cancel concurrently. If the `cancel` completes before the delay, the `race` will cancel the execution of the callback.

> You could improve this to ensure that `cancel` can't cancel the `callback`, but allow an upper cancellation to cancel the whole `race`.

---

*You can see a demo of the code running here:
https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/UP6N6wMBTQGLHPjOmXS9mw/1*